# Limits involving greatest integer functions, and analyzing behavior of functions as it tends to a value

Tags: limits, functions

I have a question, that asks me to find the following limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\bigg\lfloor\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x}\bigg\rfloor$$

Now, here's what I know, that, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} =1$$

But according to that, the answer to my question should be $1$, but it is given as $0$

Now, my book states that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1^-$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} \to 1^+$$

or, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1-h$$ $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1+h$$
How do they get this? How do I analyse the behavior of a function near around a point? A detailed explanation would really help.

Comment: Will a proof for $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x /x \to 1^-$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\tan x/x \to 1^+$ suffice?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar but then, one function is a bit less than 1 and another a bit greater than 1, what is the multiplication of them though?

Comment: @Techie5879 $(1-h)(1+h) = 1- h^2$

Comment: @Abhinav but that is in the denominator isn't it? Then taking its reciprocal makes it greater than 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the answer, it suffices to show that $\dfrac{x^2}{\sin x\tan x} < 1$ is a neighbourhood around $0$.

---

To do this, consider the function $f(x) = x^2 - \sin x \tan x$ defined on say, $[-1, 1]$.
Its derivative can be calculated as
$$f'(x) = 2x - \cos x\tan x - \sin x\sec^2x.$$
We note that $f'(0) = 0$. Also note that $f'$ is an odd function and so, the derivative changes its sign at $0$.

Now, we wish to show that $0$ is a maximum for $f$ and to do this, it suffices to just show that $f'(x) < 0$ for $x > 0$.

---

For $x > 0$ (and $x \le 1$), note that $\sin x > 0$ and $\tan x\sec x> 0$. Using AM-GM, we get that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\sin x + \tan x\sec x}{2} & \ge \sqrt{\sin x\tan x\sec x}\\
&= \sqrt{\tan^2x}\\
&= \tan x &(\because \tan x > 0)\\
&> x,
\end{align}
where the last inequality $\tan x > x$ for $x > 0$ is standard.

---

Thus, we get that $\sin x + \tan x\sec x > 2x$ and so, $f'(x) < 0$ for $x > 0$.
By odd-ness of $f'$, we get that $f'(x) > 0$ for $x < 0$.

This shows us that $0$ is a local maximum of $f$ and thus, we have that 
$$f(x) \le f(0)$$
for $x \in [-1, 1]$. (And that the inequality is strict for $x \neq 0$).

Since $f(0) = 0$, you can rearrange the above inequality to get the desired result.

Comment: How did it show that 0 is a local maximum, may I ask?

Comment: You may. Let me answer anyway - we showed that $f'(x) < 0$ for $x > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x < 0$. This shows that $f$ is increasing to the left of $0$ and decreasing to the right. This gives us that $0$ is a point of maximum.

Comment: ah right. I have another doubt.... we took the interval as $[-1,1]$, right? So can't the function change its behaviour at, let's say, 0.5....and as we need to analyse behaviour of function near about 0, wouldn't taking -1 to 1 give any errors?

Comment: Since $0.5$ falls within our interval and we proved something true for the interval, you can see it won't change its behaviour at $0.5$.

Comment: ah alright so it's proved for all values. Thanks

Comment: Another question: why did you specifically chose $[-1,1]]$ as the preferred interval to define the function? Why not....let's say.....$[-2,2]$? Or some other interval?

Comment: I did write, "say, $[0, 1]$" implying that it was arbitrary. It happened to work nicely, so I was fine. If I had taken $[-2, 2]$, then $\pi/2$ would be in the interval and give me a problem.

Comment: now it's all clarified. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

(The circle has unit radius, with $AC$ as a tangent ).

Now,
$$[\Delta OAB]<[\text{Sector} OAB]<[\Delta OAC]$$
Where $[\cdot]$ represents area.
Using the above, it is not very difficult to obtain
$$\sin x<x<\tan x$$
Or
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}<1<\frac{\tan x}{x}$$.

Comment: This does not guarantee the required limit, however. By the same argument, you should then get that $$\lim_{x\to0}\left\lfloor\dfrac{\sin x\tan x}{x^2}\right\rfloor = 0$$ as well but that's not correct.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani My answer was directed at the question "How did they get this?" - a proof that helps us understand that the limits tend to $1^-$ and $1^+$. This is exactly what was taught to me BTW. And I have no idea why it doesn't work for your example. Could you please explain why?

Comment: Yes, I agree that your solution is not incorrect in explaining the first part. I just wanted to point out that just getting those individual limits is not sufficient to arrive at the correct answer. As for "why it doesn't work": it is simply because it's not correct. It is about the same as claiming that the sum of a positive number and a negative number is positive. That is not true in general and you need greater details about the magnitude. The same happens here.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani Could you please tell me which part is incorrect?

Comment: No part is incorrect in your solution. But is insufficient, if you just have $0 < a < 1 < b$, can you conclude if $ab > 1$ or not? You cannot. In this case, you'll have to use some extra analysis as I've done in my answer. Another way to analyse this particular question could be to look at the Taylor expansion of $\sin x\tan x$ and compare it with $x^2$.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani Thanks a bunch!